# Verify that a component with data binding is created | Angular | Jasmine | Unit Test

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

Consider the following code segment...

Unit Test:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './search.component';
...

describe('AppComponent', () => {
   let component: AppComponent;
   let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

   beforeEach(async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
         imports: [
            HttpClientTestingModule,
            ...
         ],
         declarations: [
           AppComponent
         ]
      }).compileComponents();
   }));

   beforeEach(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
     fixture.detectChanges();
   });

   it('should create app component', () => {
       expect(component).toBeTruthy();
   });
});
```

Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Person } from '../../models/person';
import { PersonService } from '../../services/person.service';
...

@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   template: `Hello {{person.name}}`
})

export class AppComponent {
   person: Person;

   constructor(private personService: PersonService) { }

   ngOnit() {
      this.getPerson();
   }

   public getPerson(): void {
      this.personService.getPerson()
         .subscribe(response => this.person = response)
   }
}
```

Model:

```
export class Person {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  ...
}
```

When I run the 'should create app component' unit test I get the following error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Have tried spying and setting field as follows:

```
it('should create app component', () => {
   spyOn(component, 'person').and.returnValue(returnDummyPerson());
   expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});;

function returnDummyPerson(): Person {
   let dummyPerson = new Person();
   dummyPerson .Id = 1;
   dummyPerson .CatalogueName = 'John Doe';
   return dummyPerson;
};
```

That did not work. Please advise on how to tackle this problem.

Comment: `AppComponent` doesn't use the `HttpClient`, why is the `HttpClientTestingModule` in its tests? Where is `PersonService`? Why are you spying on a non-callable property? Also note that `ngOnit` isn't a hook - this is why you should use the lifecycle interfaces.

Comment: Mock the `personService.getPerson()` method and returns an Observable of `Person`. Plus i would use an interface as Model rather than class since there only u have properties

Comment: @jonrsharpe: app.component has a service dependency and the service leverages  the HttpClient module to make http calls to a REST API service. In the test suite I define a TestBed which builds from scratch all your angular building blocks (ngModule) as in the app.modules component.

Comment: @Ntwobike: noted

Comment: If you're testing the *component*, use a *test double* for the service dependency. And give a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an interface for Person. check below are 2 approaches. You can get an idea through them. We are using sinon in our work, great library.

```
export interface Person {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  ...
}
```

**mocking method for all the tests**

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {

const person: Person = {
    id: 1,
    name:' John'
}

class MockPersonService {
  getPerson() {
    return Observable.of(person);
  }
}

describe('AppComponent', () => {
   let component: AppComponent;
   let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

   beforeEach(async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
         imports: [
            HttpClientTestingModule,
            ...
         ],
         declarations: [
           AppComponent
         ],
         providers: [
            { provide: PersonService, useClass: MockPersonService }
         ]
      }).compileComponents();
   }));

it('should create app component', () => {
   expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

**mocking the method only for this test**

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {

const person: Person = {
    id: 1,
    name:' John'
}


it('should create app component', inject([PersonService], (personService: PersonService) => {
    spyOn(personService, 'getPerson').and.returnValue(Observalble.of(person));
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
}));
```

Comment: Could not use 'return Observable.of(person);' but used 'Observable.create((observer) =>{return observer.next(person);});' instead. Investigating why.